# Vue Component not rendering vue-notify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using this library: https://github.com/cristijora/vue-notifyjs

The documentation on the above page states: `component: {  //is rendered instead of notification message` thus I am trying to give it dynamic component so I can handle custom events. This is my code:

```
Vue.use(vueNotifyjs)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  methods: {
    addNotification(verticalAlign = 'top', horizontalAlign = 'right') {
      this.$notify({
        component: function(){
            return {
            template: '<h1>Hello</h1>'
           };
        },
        horizontalAlign: horizontalAlign,
        verticalAlign: verticalAlign,
        type: "success"
      })
    }
  }
})
```

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/2706/

But the word `Hello` is not getting rendered in the notify. Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the component key should be have an instance of Vue Component.
In your scenario, create a vue component as follows

`` Vue.component('custom-message',{
            template:`<div>Hello World</div>`
         }) ``

I have modified the fiddle with the above in this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mu4zf4xt/3/).

Hope it helps